# Perl glob returning a false positive

Tags: perl, glob

What seemed liked a straightforward piece of code most certainly didn't do what I wanted it to do.

Can somebody explain to me what it does do and why?

```
my $dir = './some/directory';

if ( -d $dir && <$dir/*> ) {
    print "Dir exists and has non-hidden files in it\n";
}
else {
    print "Dir either does not exist or has no non-hidden files in it\n";
}
```

In my test case, the directory did exist and it was empty. However, the `then` (first) section of the `if` triggered instead of the `else` section as expected.

I don't need anybody to suggest how to accomplish what I want to accomplish. I just want to understand Perl's interpretation of this code, which definitely does not match mine.

Comment: You really should look at what `<$dir/*>` is returning that you don't think exists.

Comment: I did! I printed it with `join( ', ', <$dir/*> )` or something like that and it returned what I thought it would. Which is one of the reasons I got really befuddled. @ysth's answer below seems to solve the riddle.

Comment: What `@ysth` says implies that you are changing `$dir` outside this code fragment. Is that right?

Comment: @borodin: I don't think so. He says that on the first call, it returns the first file, on the second, the second, until it has returned all, even if used in an unrelated part of the program. $dir may or may not change, it makes no difference. Perl has this very strange habit in other places, too, as I just remembered: http://upon2020.com/banter/2014/10/08/perl-really/

Comment: But if there are no files or directories that match `./some/directory/*` then `glob` should return `undef` in scalar context and an empty list in list context: there is no *first file*. I have run all the tests I can think of and I can't replicate your example. I know about `each`, but nothing I've read so far explains what you are describing.

Comment: Perl is pretty hot on context, and while it's very different from other languages it does make sense. There's also the empty regex pattern `//` which repeats the last successful match. It all hangs together if you get the human-language origins of Perl.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that your call to `glob` -- the `<$dir/*>` -- is within a loop. Can you post something that behaves as you describe that *isn't* looped?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`glob`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) (aka `<filepattern>`) in a scalar context makes it an iterator; it will return one file at a time each time it is called, and will not respond to changes in the pattern (e.g. a different $dir) until it has finished iterating over the initial results; I suspect this is causing the trouble you see.

The easy answer is to always use it in list context, like so:

```
if( -d $dir && ( () = <$dir/*> ) ) {
```

glob may only really be used safely in scalar context in code you will execute more than once if you are *absolutely sure* you will exhaust the iterator before you try to start a new iteration.  Most of the time it's just easier to avoid glob in scalar context altogether.

Comment: What about `scalar(<$dir/*>)`?

Comment: scalar just gives its operand scalar context, which it already had in the original code.

Comment: I actually tried `scalar(<$dir/*>)` for that reason, but apparently that wasn't good enough.

Comment: @ysth: I don't follow. Why does `scalar glob './empty_dir/*'` not return `undef`? Are you suggesting that the real-life code modifies `$dir` between calls to `glob`?

Comment: @Borodin: if it does, there is certainly a problem; if it doesn't, there still is a problem because `scalar glob './not_empty_dir/*'` will occasionally return undef after the first time

Comment: @ysth: Please be more clear. "*does*" and *"doesn't"* what? Sure, `scalar glob './not_empty_dir/*'` may return `undef` if it has been called before and returned a node name, but the OP's problem is that `-d $dir && <$dir/*>` is evaluating as *true* on an *empty* directory, and I cannot see how your answer explains that unless his `$dir` is being modified, which he denies.

Comment: I'm sorry, but -1 until you explain this :)

Comment: does = code modifies $dir between calls, doesn't = it doesn't.  I was assuming we weren't getting the whole story, yes, and leaping at the most likely culprit.  Other possible, but much less likely, problems with his code: current directory is not what he thinks it is and $dir is a relative path; $dir contains spaces.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that `@ysth` is on the right track, but repeated calls to `glob` in scalar context *don't* generate false positives.

For example

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

say scalar glob('/usr/*'), "\n";

say scalar glob('/usr/*'), "\n";
```

**output**

```
/usr/bin

/usr/bin
```

But what *is* true is that *any single call* to `glob` maintains a state, so if I have

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

for my $dir ( '/sys', '/usr', '/sys', '/usr' ) {
  say scalar glob("$dir/*"), "\n";
}
```

**output**

```
/sys/block

/sys/bus

/sys/class

/sys/dev
```

So clearly that `glob` statement inside the loop is maintaining a state, and ignoring the changes to `$dir`.

This is similar to the way that the `pos` (and corresponding `\G` regex anchor) has a state per scalar variable, and how `print` without a specific file handle prints to the *last selected* handle. In the end it is how all of Perl works, with the *it* variable `$_` being the ultimate example.